# Question on solving an optimization problem using Variable splitting and ADMM

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Tell me if I have found the right approach to the following optimization problem:

$$ 
min_{x} \frac{1}{2}\left \| Ax-b \right \|_2^2
\\
s.t. \  \  \Phi v=x  \ , \ {x^T(1-x)}=0
$$

$A$ and $\Phi$ represent matrices, $x$, $b$ and $v$ vectors. The final answer for $x$ should have binary {0,1} values only, since the operator $A$ only accepts binary inputs.

Will ADMM and variable splitting solve this?

Comment: Are you sure about the first constraint?  It just gives you the solution for x as $x=\Phi v$.  Also, can you specify the dimensions of $A$ and $\Phi$?

Comment: The first constrain can be relaxed by $|\Phi v-x|<\epsilon$, A is has more columns than rows and $\Phi$ is fat (over determined system)

Comment: ADMM would builde the augmented Lagrangian for the problem and then alternatingly minimize between $v$ and $x$ with suitable update for the Lagrange multiplier. You may get intro trouble due to the nonlinear (in fact bilinear) constraint for $x$ (which I interpret componentwise, right?) resulting in a non-convex subproblem for the $x$ minimization (and also no convergence result I knows will be applicable).

Comment: *Will ADMM and variable splitting solve this?* I think you have to try this to get an answer.  (Implementation seems straightforward and monitoring descent of the objective also. Checking second order sufficient conditions seems also possible…)